# How to search and replace code in Delphi TBCEditor

Tags: search, replace, editor, delphi-xe, rich-text-editor

I need help. I was compiling a code editor. How to **search** and **replace** code in Delphi TBCEditor.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. Doesn't `TBCEditor`'s documentation tell you how to accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Search text in TBCEditor:

```
Editor.Search.SearchText := Edit1.Text;
```

This displays the search results:

[image]